# PermissionChecker without activity or support library

Tags: android, permissions, android-support-library

I'm developing a library independent to android support libraries

> android-support-v*.jar

Is there any way or sort of classes I can use for app permission check. 
Means I've to check app permission like Location etc without using android support libraries. can someone please help? thanks

Comment: It is not possible without activity, but it is possible without support library. Check my code: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: I think your code having clue which @commansWare suggesting. I can check for context and if context is instance of Activity then ask for permission. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can request permissions without activity, but to get the result immediately, you will need activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native methods on `Activity` and `Context` to check for runtime permissions, such as `checkSelfPermission()` on `Context` and `requestPermissions()` on `Activity`. However, you will need to have your own smarts to *not* call those methods on devices running Android 5.1 or older.